# gameobjectを生成する

Tags: c#, unity3d

ゲームオブジェクトをスクリプト上で生成する方法はありますか？
具体的には元にあったgameobjectをdestroyしたあと、別のgameobjectをその場に
生成するといったものですが

Instantiate(gameobject)で実行してみましたが、gameobject(clone)となるだけで
gameobjectは画面上にはないので、生成はできてないようです。

上記を実行する方法はありますか？ unity2d  c#です

Answer (score 1):

UnityとC#始めて2カ月目の者ですが、僕の理解の範囲で回答します。

GameObjectとは「魂」のようなののだと思います。魂には肉体がないので、GameObjectを作っても画面上には見えません。
肉体に対応するMeshやMesh RendererのようなものをGameObjectに追加すれば見えるようになりますが、以下がとりあえず簡単な方法として実行できます。

```
    GameObject myGO = GameObject.CreatePrimitive (PrimitiveType.Cube);
```

上記ではCubeの外装（+色々)を持つGameObjectを作成できます。

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CreatePrimitive.html

なお、GameObjectには外装を持たずにスクリプトだけを付けて処理させることもできます。デザインにおいてはEmptyGameObjectを作って、それにスクリプトを追加することに対応します。これは目に見えないお化け(天使、悪魔, whatever)が裏で何かやってくれる、というのに対応します。